# React insert component inside of the parent Route's component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm developing a forum in react as an exercise. I have the following Route structure(not complete, pseudocode)

```
<Routes>
  //fixed Toolbar
  <Route index element={<Toolbar />}> 
    //view of all the threads in the post
    <Route path="thread/:threadId" element={<ThreadItem />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

In my ThreadItem component, which displays the posts in the thread, I want to insert pagination links into the Toolbar component.

Is it possible to insert content from one component into another component? Does It work with Portals? Is it clean?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for specific help with. Can you [edit] to clarify in better detail what exactly you are wanting, or trying, to do, and what any specific issue is?

Comment: What pagination are you referring to. What is the issue? You haven't provided enough code to provide any context for what you are trying to do or what any issue is. See [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for clarifying why it was closed, I see it more as a general question than a specific problem which is why I boiled it down to pseudocode instead of working code. And Since I didn't know how to do what I wanted to do, I couldn't provide a reproducible example. Seeing the first answer it was probably a bad idea to begin with. Content that is going to be rendered in the Toolbar component should probably be written inside the Toolbar component and not inside of the ThreadItem component.

Comment: I added an explanation about pagination links, even though I think it doesn't matter for the question. For me it can stay like this, I have my answer and maybe other people find it useful. I didn't find the question unclear to begin with but my view might be biased of course

Comment: Sorry, went on vacation there for a bit. Honestly your latest explanation has made it more confusing to me, but that's probably because in React we don't generally "inject" content into other components. I was thinking you could accomplish what you want with a layout route component with the toolbar and paginator.... but that's basically what it looks like you already have. Seeing a more concrete example for what you are wanting to do would likely clear up ambiguities and uncertainties.

Comment: you can inject content into components that make use of props.children, so I don't think it is a strange concept in react. The solution with useLocation doesn't work for me so I'll probably drop the nested routes and actually use props.children to get the links into the Toolbar.

Comment: `props.children` is just normal React though, a parent component is passing props down to a child component. I guess if you want to call that "injection" that's fair, but that doesn't exactly sound like what you are trying to do here. Like I said, a better [mcve] might illustrate better to us what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It is what I wanted to do, but from somewhere else than the parent, but since that doesn't seem to work in react or be a good thing, I have to move the Toolbar inside the root component of my threaditem route. It's probably cleaner to use a custom prop to pass components instead of props.children.

Comment: Thanks for your time but definitely not thanks for closing the question. In your link it clearly states "When asking a debugging question" so I really don't get why you insist on it, it is not a debugging question. How should I give a reproducible example when asking "how" to do something? The moment I have a reproducible example my question is answered.

Comment: I think you are reading that too literally. It's a give and take. You give a good enough  code example for what you are trying to do, describe the issue or problem with that code, and we can see where that code goes sideways and help. You've provided pseudocode, but we're saying that doesn't provide enough context what you are trying to do. Just asking if something is possible is too broad. You are correct, if you have 100% working code that did what you want then there's no point to Stackoverflow, but that's not what a MCRE is in this context.

Comment: Why we? How many people other than you voted for closing ?

Comment: "We" - the royal we, the Stackoverflow community. We have standards. How many people? It takes 3 close votes to close a question unless it's gold badge holder closing a question as a duplicate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254586/discussion-between-nigel-n-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location#uselocation) hook inside your `<Toolbar />` to get the currently active route.

If the active route matches your `:threadId` route, render the pagination links.

---

Something like this could fit your needs

```
import { useLocation , matchPath } from "react-router-dom";

const location = useLocation();

const pagination = (matchPath('your-path-to-match', location.pathname))
    && (<PaginationLinks />);
```